# Which one is light: REST or GRPC

Tags: rest, grpc

I need to create an API, which will be accessed by very remote places, where internet is very slow and weak. What would be a light API, gRPC or REST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion Rest and GRPC are different technology and they don't be a rival. The GRPC  can be preferred on streaming progress on the other hand this is not acceptable for rest :)

If you want to still compare grpc and rest speed, I can share a link for you.

I think you can get the performance problem answer at the given link below

https://www.yonego.com/nl/why-milliseconds-matter/#gref

Spoiler: the light load progress Rest can be faster than grpc but if you compare them under high load, GRPC can win this race :)